# Delete a particular record on click

Tags: android

Friends,
I have a file that contains a series of activities.Upon the action is performed new data gets added into the file(txt file).
When a particular activity is launched in  a listview where I am displaying a list of activites.Please refer to the image. On the click of the button I wish to delete that particular entry and also modify the records into the txt file. Please share the same code with me.

Thanks,in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Get the position of the button click.. Use this position to remove that particular item from the dataholder..

```
yourdataHolder.remove(position);
```

then finally notify the change in the listview, using `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Let me know if you still have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. try this

   ```
    delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               // adapter is object of adapter
                               // dataList is arrayList
                               // variable for listview

                                 listview.invalidateViews()
               adapter.remove(dataList.get(position));
                               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

           }
       });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Get the position of item click, remove the item from the adapter.
And notify data changed to the adapter.